# i have sql error syntax when i make trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'd like to create a trigger which create `id_pembayaran` on pembayaran table, but there's a sql syntax error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER id_bayar 
    BEFORE INSERT ON pembayaran
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pembayaran INTO @idpembayaran;
    SELECT id_jenis_pembayaran, IF(id_jenis_pembayaran = 'DP', 
       SET new.id_pembayaran = CONCAT('DP','-',   DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y%m%d'),'-',@idpembayaran+1),
       SET new.id_pembayaran = CONCAT('LNS','-', DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y%m%d'),'-',@idpembayaran+1)
      ) FROM pembayaran;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what is the error msg?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
    WHEN id_jenis_pembayaran = 'DP' THEN
       SET new.id_pembayaran =' at line 7

Comment: cant see any CASE statement in your code. where did you get the error from? anyway, try `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @idpembayaran FROM pembayaran;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to *set* values in each row:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER id_bayar 
    BEFORE INSERT ON pembayaran
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.id_pembayaran =
        (SELECT (CASE WHEN new.id_jenis_pembayaran = 'DP'
                      THEN CONCAT('DP','-',   DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y%m%d'), '-', COUNT(*) + 1)
                      ELSE CONCAT('LNS','-', DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y%m%d'), '-', COUNT(*) + 1)
                 END)
         FROM pembayaran
        );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Isewa07 . . . MySQL can be finicky about trigger syntax.  I updated to what should be a correct version.

Comment: finally it works too, but the result is always the first condition

Comment: @Isewa07 . . . I would expect the second condition.  The `when` needs to be modified with `new` (which I changed).